# ExtJs 3.4, ExtDirect, Symfony and PHP 8.2 -> no data is returned

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, extjs3, php-8.2

We are currently upgrading PHP form 7.1 to PHP 8.2 for a legacy application which uses Apache, FriendsOfSymfony 1.5.15, ExtJs 3.4 and ExtDirect.

The following problem occurs: Sending a request to the Symfony backend creates the result as expected. The ExtDirect plugin, dsExtDirectPlugin, handles the request and response until a certain point in the dsExtDirectRouter.class.php where the code echos the response from the Symfony endpoint:

```
    echo json_encode(self::$response);
```

From this point on Symfony shutdowns down logging,... and I expect that the response echod is used in JavaScript from that point on, but in the Firefox development tools, I see "no data available" in the network tab. So the output doesn't seem to come to the frontend / is suppressed from being echod?

Does anyone have a clue what can cause this? Do I need an additional php or apache config?

Thanks and kind regards,

Dirk

Comment: you forgot to mention the Symfony version.

Comment: It's Friends Of Symfony 1.5.15, a Symfony fork created for PHP 8.2 support.

Comment: So it is for a Symfony 1.4. Anyway I never used this kind of tools to continue to use very old applications because they always ends to result a waste of time and a never ending source of problems. I cannot help you here sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my prolbem: Fast CGI module for Apache is installed and therefore the fastcgi_finish_request method was called. Fast CGI had to be uninstalled so the communication between ExtJs 3.4 <-> ExtDirect <-> Symfony 1 works.